# Doxygen with Qt defines

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, doxygen

I have class definition like:

```
class A Q_DECL_FINAL: public QThread
```

Problem that `doxygen` parses that incorrect! My class in `doxygen` docs and diagrams calls `Q_DECL_FINAL`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this:

```
class MovableLabel Q_DECL_FINAL: public QLabel
```

To ignore `Q_DECL_FINAL` (in `doxygen`) you should use next:

```
class MovableLabel /** @cond */ Q_DECL_FINAL /** @endcond */: public QLabel
```

In this case you will get correct class name in doc generated by `doxygen` and true meaning of `Q_DECL_FINAL` during compilation, so next will not work:

```
class Der : MovableLabel //error
{

};
```

Also `Q_DECL_FINAL` is not a `typedef`. It is something like:

```
#ifdef Q_COMPILER_EXPLICIT_OVERRIDES
# define Q_DECL_OVERRIDE override
# define Q_DECL_FINAL final //here our keyword
#else
# ifndef Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
#  define Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
# endif
# ifndef Q_DECL_FINAL
#  define Q_DECL_FINAL //just nothing, if c++11 not enabled
# endif
#endif
```

And `Q_COMPILER_EXPLICIT_OVERRIDES` is:

```
#    if __has_feature(cxx_override_control)
#      define Q_COMPILER_EXPLICIT_OVERRIDES
#    endif
```

[Code from here.](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h)